# Using a third party web service in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, wsdl, webmethod

I am trying to build an app in VS Pro 2012 (VB.NET) that will invoke RoyalMail's MailMark WSDL which has methods such as RetrieveActiveSupplyChains which are expecting a single parameter (request).

I have used svcutil with the /l:vb switch to download the WSDL and referenced it in my project and I can see methods being exposed once I have done

```
    Dim client As PosterUploadClient = New PosterUploadClient()
```

Now typing client. brings up all the methods I expect to see and I can pass authentication and see the state change when I do client.open() but what I can't figure out is how to provide the parameters the actual methods need. According to their documentation, RetrieveActiveSupplyChains doesn't need a parameter but they have provided an xml example of the request structure so my assumption is that I'd need to construct this as xml with the appropriate values and send it as "request"?

Does this sound right? I know this is probably meat and veg for a web programmer but not something I have attempted before. The xml they supplied as an example looks like the below:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://rm-manifest.com/2014/01/service/IPosterUpload/RetrieveAllActiveSupplyChains</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:ab5e32a3-812e-4d91-97a8-de00a08874e9</a:MessageID>
    <a:ReplyTo>
      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://rm-manifest.com/PosterUpload2/PosterUpload.svc/service</a:To>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
        <u:Created>2014-10-03T14:32:58.480Z</u:Created>
        <u:Expires>2014-10-03T14:37:58.480Z</u:Expires>
      </u:Timestamp>
      <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-dfaaf0b0-3823-4f75-b607-33f7434295dc-1">
        <o:Username>NetworkAccess</o:Username>
        <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">p1</o:Password>
      </o:UsernameToken>
    </o:Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <RetrieveAllActiveSupplyChains xmlns="http://rm-manifest.com/2014/01/service">
      <request xmlns:b="http://rm-manifest.com/2014/01/messages" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
    </RetrieveAllActiveSupplyChains>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

But I'm still not sure how it actually needs to be submitted, certainly if I read that sample one in with a new xmltextreader it doesn't like it with the following error message

```
Value of type 'System.Xml.XmlTextReader' cannot be converted to 'MM_TEST.Mosaic.EIB.PosterUploadService.Core.Messages.RetrieveActiveSupplyChainsRequest'
```

My assumption was the WSDL replaces the need to actually create a "New HttpRequest" in my code but not sure. I've done a lot of googling but not getting anything that quite works like this

The WSDL is here if this helps:
https://customertest.rm-manifest.com/PosterUpload/PosterUpload.svc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the method. The provided XML is what is actually sent to the server by the WCF proxy when you call the method. You don't need to use it at all.

If you use a tool like Fiddler, you'll see that simply calling `client.RetrieveAllActiveSupplyChains` will send an HTTP request with a body similar to the XML sample.

In fact, everything outside the `RetrieveAllActiveSupplyChains` tag isn't related to the method at all - it's security and addressing data used to establish and execute a connection with a web service in general. All of this is handled by WCF.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so for methods that do need me to send parameters such as SupplyChainID, what then would be the syntax? Although if I just call the method on it's own it says Argument not specified for parameter 'request' of 'Public Function RetrieveActiveSupplyChains(request As Mosaic.EIB.PosterUploadService.Core.Messages.RetrieveActiveSupplyChainsRequest) As Mosaic.EIB.PosterUploadService.Core.Messages.RetrieveActiveSupplyChainsResponse'

Comment: Just pass the id (which I assume is an integer) as a parameter when calling the method. And make sure you supply parameter values for all parameters. The error message says that you forgot to pass the parameter at all. If the parameter expects an object, create an object of that type and set its values

Comment: Then I get Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to 'MM_TEST.Mosaic.EIB.PosterUploadService.Core.Messages.RetrieveActiveSupplyChainsRequest'. I think that's the crux of my problem, I know what parameters each method "should" require and what format (string, int etc) but all the methods only accept one "request" parameter

Comment: What you call parameters are properties on this request object

Comment: Yes that makes sense, although the request object could vary from method to method I still don't know how I populate this with the values required by the method. For example, the CreateBatch() method needs SupplyChainID (string 7), ManifestID (int) and BatchReference (string 50) whereas SubmitBatch() needs BatchID (int) and TotalItemCount(int). The bit I am clearly not getting is what sort of object I need to create that will hold these so I can pass it to the method.

Comment: "string 7" is not the type of the property of the request object. Look at the properties of the request object. Do you know how to use Object Browser in the View menu to look at an object?

Comment: I mean, you say you don't know what sort of object you need to create, and my question is, _why_ don't you know?

Comment: There is no "request" in Object Browser, the methods themselves are all there under the main PosterUploadClient but they only have the default "objects" there (Finalize, New etc).

Comment: '     <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(),  _
   System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0"),  _
   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name:="RetrieveActiveSupplyChainsRequest", [Namespace]:="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Mosaic.EIB.PosterUploadService.Core.Messa"& _ 
   "ges")>  _
  Partial Public Class RetrieveActiveSupplyChainsRequest
   Inherits Object
   Implements System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
   
   Private extensionDataField As System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject'

Comment: <System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action:="http://tempuri.org/IPosterUpload/RetrieveActiveSupplyChains", ReplyAction:="http://tempuri.org/IPosterUpload/RetrieveActiveSupplyChainsResponse")>  _
    Function RetrieveActiveSupplyChains(ByVal request As Mosaic.EIB.PosterUploadService.Core.Messages.RetrieveActiveSupplyChainsRequest) As Mosaic.EIB.PosterUploadService.Core.Messages.RetrieveActiveSupplyChainsResponse